# dealing with input:focus + label in css

Tags: html, css

If I set focus on an element I will get access to the next label (as example) by using the + in css.

```
input:focus + label {
     color:red;
}
```

But how do I get one more or the next element (In my example the .arrow)?

```
<div class="fade">
    <input type="text" required name="field1" placeholder="Field 1 Triggered on Focus/Blur" />
    <label>type text</label>
    <div class="arrow"></div>
</div>
```

I made a jsfiddel [here](http://jsfiddle.net/9ww8t/3/).
On the first input I have a label floating to top.
On the second, I change the corner-arrow (right upper corner in input field) to another color.
Now, I would like to combine both.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll need to be consistent with your markup, but you can just use another sibling selector:

```
input:focus + label {
     color:red;
}

input:focus + label + div.arrow {
     border-top-color: #333;
     border-right-color: #333;
}
```

Comment: thx it works. what do you mean with :"You'll need to be consistent with your markup." Is there a better markup?

Comment: No, I just mean with adjacent selectors, your elements must come in the order specified by your selector: an input and then a label and then `div.arrow`

Answer (score 0):

You should write css as below.

```
input:focus + label, input:focus + label + div {
   color:red;
}
```